# Truffle Setup Fails for some Truffle commands

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

I'm new to truffle and I have been following this tutorial below to set up the sample pet shop project:

http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

I have all the stuff that is required to set this example on my Mac. But when I give the truffle develop command, I get the following error:

```
Joe-MacBook-Pro:pet-shop-tutorial joe$ truffle develop
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

Here is my truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {
   networks: {
      development: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "*" // Match any network id
      }
   }
};
```

What is the problem now with what I'm doing?

I'm using truffle version:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:pet-shop-tutorial joe$ truffle version
Truffle v3.4.11 (core: 3.4.11)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)
```

Comment: No node run in your localhost. Please start if u already have or use testrpc

Comment: But I thought I would use truffle for this? I don't want to use testrpc. Dosn't truffle come with a built in ethereum client?

Comment: What version of truffle are you using?

Comment: I have edited my post with the truffle and solidity version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using truffle 3.x.x. which doesn't come with it's own testrpc replacement.

If you don't want to use testrpc, update to 4.x and test using the truffle develop command.

If you don't want to update, you'll have to start testrpc on another terminal window.